# I can't merge to column AA

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I'm merging cells quite happily till I get to `AA`.

Works fine:

`wks.Range("A1:Z1").Merge`

Fails:

`wks.Range("A1:AA1").Merge`

Fails when creating column tags on the fly, so I've tried hard coding the issue (as above). Issue still occurs.

Any ideas?

I've tried hard coding `$A$1:$AA$1` with same failure.

Run-time error'1004':

> Application defined or object defined error

Comment: Protected sheet?  Works fine for me.

Comment: Might be something else happening in your code causing an unexpected issue? Is it giving you the error when you only run the single line above?

Comment: Samuel, it definitely fails on this particular line. I've stopped the code writing the column header on the fly and have resorted to hard coding the issue. Works fine for "A1:Z1". It fails as soon as I go one column further to "A1:AA1".  Pretty strange.

Comment: Works for me - what's the value of `wks` when it fails?